# Multinomial HMM with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, hidden-markov-models

I've been trying to implement my hmm model in pyspark, but haven't found any example so far so I can make it work with my code.
Can anyone help me? Here's my .py code

```
import numpy as np
from hmmlearn import hmm

states = ['DET','ADJ','NN','V']
n_states = len(states)

observations = ['the','a','green','big','old','might','book','plants','people','person','John','wash','washes','loves','reads','books']
n_observations = len(observations)

start_probability = np.array([0.5,0.1,0.3,0.1])

transition_probability = np.array([
        [0,   0,   0,   0.5],
        [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2],
        [0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.2],
        [0,   0.1, 0.5, 0.1]
]).T

emission_probability = np.array([
    [0.7, 0, 0, 0],
    [0.3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0.1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0.4, 0, 0],
    [0, 0.4, 0, 0],
    [0, 0.1, 0, 0.2],
    [0, 0, 0.3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0.2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0.2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0.1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0.1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0.1, 0.3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0.2],
    [0, 0, 0, 0.1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0.19],
    [0, 0, 0, 0.01]
]).T

model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=n_states, init_params="")
model.startprob_=start_probability
model.transmat_=transition_probability

model.emissionprob_=emission_probability

# predict a sequence of hidden states based on visible states
bob_says = np.array([[10,5,11]]).T #transpose

#model = model.fit(bob_says)
logprob, alice_hears = model.decode(bob_says, algorithm="viterbi")
print("Bob says:", ", ".join(map(lambda x: observations[x], bob_says.T[0])))

print("Alice hears:", ", ".join(map(lambda x: states[x], alice_hears)))
```

I've readed the documentation for the gmm learn but can't seem to implement the hmm one.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't see anything related to Spark or PySpark in your code. Perhaps you should remove those tags or elaborate on how you want to use the features of Spark to solve your problem.